# Jenkins Jacoco plugin and Maven release plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, release, jacoco-maven-plugin

I noticed that when using the maven release plugin and the Jacoco plugin, after a build success it releases and then only it checks the Jacoco test coverage. My question is about is there any possible way to run the Jacoco test coverage first and then if it passes only release using the maven release plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [jacoco maven plugin contains](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html) a `check` goals which could handle such things where you can define rules:

```xml
<rules>
  <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
    <element>BUNDLE</element>
    <limits>
      <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
        <minimum>0.80</minimum>
      </limit>
      <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
        <counter>CLASS</counter>
        <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
        <maximum>0</maximum>
      </limit>
    </limits>
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Or defining a minimum like:

```xml
<rules>
  <rule>
    <element>CLASS</element>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>*Test</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <limits>
      <limit>
        <counter>LINE</counter>
        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
        <minimum>50%</minimum>
      </limit>
    </limits>
  </rule>
</rules>
```

This means you need to add the `check` goal into your build...

Comment: It was useful when configuring from the pom.xml. any suggestions when using it via the Jenkins api in the post build actions?